# How many git fetches can I do at once without causing issues?

Tags: git

I'm using `git` for code deployment to a large number of target locations.

I'm guessing that if I were to run `git fetch origin` on all of the target locations at the same time, it would cause something like a DDOS attack.

How intensive is the `git fetch` command? Is it dangerous to run it 100+ times simultaneously? (I'm guessing the answer here is "yes".... in which case, what is the best solution to this issue? staggering the fetch? using multiple remotes?)

Comment: `git fetch` runs commands on the remote, typically through https or ssh. How heavy-weight those commands are depend on the server, the repository/ies, the network, and so on.

Comment: Who’s hosting this?  Any commercial git hosting provider should have DDoS prevention, because even creating a packfile is reasonably computationally expensive, so it would be easy to exhaust cpu cores by doing fetches in parallel.  But if you’re just running your own git server, it should be relatively easy to DoS.  (Source: I worked on GitHub’s and Azure Repo’s).

Comment: I'm running my own git server, so from what you're saying it sounds like DDOS could be an issue if I execute too many git fetches at once. I'll need to find a way to avoid doing that, while still executing the fetch everywhere in a reasonable amount of time... :/